# ValueError When Performing scipy.stats test on Pandas Column Selection by Row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

The goal is to create a new column in a pandas column that stores the value of a KS D-statistic, `df['ks']`.  The KS statistic is generated between two groups of columns in that dataframe, `grp1` and `grp2`:

```
# sample dataframe
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dic = {'gene': ['x','y','z','n'],
        'cell_a': [1, 5, 8,9],
        'cell_b': [8, 5, 4,9],
        'cell_c': [8, 6, 1,1],
        'cell_d': [1, 2, 7,1],
        'cell_e': [5, 7, 9,1],
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df.set_index('gene', inplace=True)
df['ks'] = np.nan

# sample groups
grp1 = ['cell_a','cell_b']
grp2 = ['cell_d','cell_e']
```

So the D-statistic for gene x would be `stats.ks_2samp([1,5], [1,6])[0]`, gene y would be `stats.ks_2samp([5,2], [1,7])[0]`, etc.  Attempt is below:

```
# attempt 1 to fill in KS stat
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    df.ix[idx, 'ks'] = stats.ks_2samp(df[grp1], df[grp2])[0]
```

However, when I attempt to fill the `ks` series, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

My question has two parts: 1) What does it mean for an object to be "too deep for an array", and 2) how can I accomplish the same thing without iteration?

Comment: Change that line to - `df.loc[idx, 'ks'] = stats.ks_2samp(row[grp1], row[grp2])[0]` since you're operating per row basis and not the entire `DF` object per se. Also, it's better to use `.loc` for the assignment purposes as accessing via `.ix` would soon be deprecated in the upcoming versions.

Comment: Still too deep for the array.  Still don't know what that means or how to fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KS calculation in the loop was getting a "too deep" error because I needed to pass it a 1-D array for each distribution to test:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[idx, 'ks'] = stats.ks_2samp(df.loc[idx, grp1], (df.loc[idx, grp2]))[0]
```

My previous attempt used a 2-D array instead.  That is what was causing it to be "too deep"