# Scipy Curve Fit: "Result from function call is not a proper array of floats."

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a 2D Gaussian with an offset to a 2D array. The code is based on this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566379/fitting-a-2d-gaussian-function-using-scipy-optimize-curve-fit-valueerror-and-m) (which was written for Python2 while I am using Python3, therefore some changes were necessary to make it run somewhat):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

n_pixels = 2400

def twoD_Gaussian(data_list, amplitude, xo, yo, sigma_x, sigma_y, offset):
    x = data_list[0]
    y = data_list[1]
    theta = 0 # don't care about theta for the moment but want to leave the option in
    a = (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    b = -(np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_y**2)
    c = (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    g = offset + amplitude*np.exp( - (a*((x-xo)**2) + 2*b*(x-xo)*(y-yo) + c*((y-yo)**2)))
    return g 

x = np.linspace(1, n_pixels, n_pixels) #starting with 1 because proper data is from a fits file
y = np.linspace(1, n_pixels, n_pixels)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

amp = -3
x0, y0 = n_pixels/2, n_pixels/2
sigma_x, sigma_y = 100, 100
offset = -1

initial_guess = np.asarray([amp, x0, y0, sigma_x, sigma_y, offset])

data_array = np.asarray([x, y])

testmap = twoD_Gaussian(data_array, initial_guess[0], initial_guess[1], initial_guess[2], initial_guess[3], initial_guess[4], initial_guess[5])

popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(twoD_Gaussian, data_array, testmap, p0=initial_guess)
```

However, I first get a value error:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Which the traceback then traces to:

```
error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

From what I understood in other threads with this other, this has to do with some part of the argument not being properly defined as an array, but e.g. as a symbolic object, which I do not understand since the output testmap (which is working as expected) is actually a numpy array, and all input into curve_fit is also either a numpy array or the function itself. What is the exact issue and how can I solve it?

edit: the full error if I try to run it from console is:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fit-2dgauss.py", line 41, in <module>
    popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(twoD_Gaussian, data_array, test, p0=initial_guess)
  File "/users/drhiem/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 784, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "/users/drhiem/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 423, in leastsq
gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

I just noticed that instead of "error", it's now "minpack.error". I ran this in an ipython console environment beforehand for testing purposes, so maybe that difference is down to that, not sure how much this difference matters.

Comment: which line is throwing that error?

Comment: @PaulH the last one, I'll edit in the full console output if I try to run the script from console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data_array` is `(2, 2400, 2400)` `float64` (from added print)

`testmap` is `(2400, 2400)` `float64`  (again a diagnostic print)

`curve_fit` docs talk about M length or (k,M) arrays.

You are providing (2,N,N) and (N,N) shape arrays.

Lets try flattening the N,N dimensions:

In the objective function:

```
def twoD_Gaussian(data_list, amplitude, xo, yo, sigma_x, sigma_y, offset):
    x = data_list[0]
    y = data_list[1]
    x = x.reshape(2400,2400)
    y = y.reshape(2400,2400)
    theta = 0 # don't care about theta for the moment but want to leave the option in
    a = (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    b = -(np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_y**2)
    c = (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    g = offset + amplitude*np.exp( - (a*((x-xo)**2) + 2*b*(x-xo)*(y-yo) + c*((y-yo)**2)))
    return g.ravel()
```

and

and in the calls:

```
testmap = twoD_Gaussian(data_array.reshape(2,-1), initial_guess[0], initial_guess[1], initial_guess[2], initial_guess[3], initial_guess[4], initial_guess[5])
# shape (5760000,) float64
print(type(testmap),testmap.shape, testmap.dtype)
popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(twoD_Gaussian, data_array.reshape(2,-1), testmap, p0=initial_guess)
```

And it runs:

```
1624:~/mypy$ python3 stack65587542.py 
(2, 2400, 2400) float64
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (5760000,) float64
```

`popt` and `pcov`:

```
[-3.0e+00  1.2e+03  1.2e+03  1.0e+02  1.0e+02 -1.0e+00] 
[[ 0. -0. -0.  0.  0. -0.]
 [-0.  0. -0. -0. -0. -0.]
 [-0. -0.  0. -0. -0. -0.]
 [ 0. -0. -0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -0. -0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-0. -0. -0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

The `popt` values are the same as `initial_guess` as expected with the exact `testmap`.

So the basic issue is that you did not take the documented specifications seriously.  That

> ValueError: object too deep for desired array

error message is a bit obscure, though I vaguely recall seeing it before.  Sometimes we get errors like this when inputs are ragged arrays and the result arrays is object dtype. But here it's simply a matter of shape.

A past SO with similar problem and fix:

[Scipy curve_fit for Two Dimensions Not Working - Object Too Deep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53284842/scipy-curve-fit-for-two-dimensions-not-working-object-too-deep)

[ValueError When Performing scipy.stats test on Pandas Column Selection by Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827228/valueerror-when-performing-scipy-stats-test-on-pandas-column-selection-by-row)

[Fitting a 2D Gaussian function using scipy.optimize.curve_fit - ValueError and minpack.error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566379/fitting-a-2d-gaussian-function-using-scipy-optimize-curve-fit-valueerror-and-m)

This is just a subset of SO with the same error message.  Other `scipy` functions produce it.  And often the problem is with shapes like (m,1) instead of (N,N).  I'd be tempted to close this as a duplicate, but my long answer with debugging details may be instructive.